# Diff-in-Diff analysing policy affecting parental income that may affect child health

Tags: stata

I am interested to see if a particular policy that increases parental income may impact child health for mothers and fathers. So it would be a diff-in-diff model I would be running. Below is my regression model:
Click image for larger version

[image]

Here `Post` is a dummy for period after policy, `Treated` is a dummy for those who receive the treatment, and `X` is a vector of parental controls such as age, gender, qualification, etc. Would my above regression be correct if I ran it separately for mothers and fathers?

I also wondered whether I should include another vector variable controlling for child characteristics such as age and gender.

The code for mothers and fathers separate diff in diff regressions are:

```
regress child_health post#treat mother_age qualification marital status, robust

regress child_health post#treat father_age qualification marital status, robust
```

In addition, I was wondering if there may be more than one child in the household, and I would run this regression for each child, so I was wondering if I have to cluster the standard errors or how I would do this.

Comment: This is essentially a statistical question and as such off-topic here. Possibly suited for Cross Validated.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1723080-did-regression